# ASP.NET - Reusing a UI across multiple projects?

Tags: user-interface, asp.net-3.5

Here's the situation:

A while ago, I created a back-end interface for adding/modifying/deleting items in a DB. It was created as an individual project, and we are still using that particular instance of the code. I will call this "version 1".

A little while after I completed this, I duplicated the code and integrated it into a much larger project. I copied all of the DB tables that were used in the original project's DB into the DB that this project was already using. I also had to duplicate the front-end here, but it's the back-end that I'm concerned with. The requirements for this interface (I will call this "version 2") were a bit more complex, so I had to keep working on it and also make some modifications to the DB tables.

It is essentially 2 branched versions of the same interface. However, version 1 has not received much attention since version 2's conception. Some of the changes I made in version 2 were not just new features, but improvements/bug fixes that are relevant to version 1. I should have made these changes on version 1 as well, but unfortunately I didn't. Going forward I will need to make improvements to both versions, and some of these improvements will apply to both of them.

I would really like to merge the 2 interfaces somehow, as I'm quite sure that it will reduce my workload in the long run. Frankly, I would like to *abandon* version 1 and adapt the version 2 UI to version 1's DB.

My first instinct is to transport everything to a user control that has a "version" attribute. The version would then be used to hide/show the controls that are or aren't relevant to that version, and it would also be used to determine what DB queries/stored procedures to use. The issue with this is that this whole interface spans across 5 pages. A few of these pages are opened up as dialogs from another one of the 5 pages. I suppose that I could simply have one div per interface, and then when !IsPostBack, I can set the Visible property of each div according to a querystring variable. However, this seems like it would be awfully messy and it would be a LOT of code and markup on one page. I guess alternatively I could have 5 user controls, but this just seems like an odd design.

Are there any other viable solutions?

Answer (score 0):

i've been maintaining 4 products with nearly identical interfaces:

- they started from one project
- got cloned and branched
- i've been slowly re-merging them

The best suggestion i have is try to some up with a UI that works for both, and switch both to using that.

After that i have a *project-local* settings file, which defines which features should not exist in one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't quite understand the logistics of how to implement this. Basically for version 2, it's not running as a stand-alone project; right now it's just a folder in the project of our main product. It should use the main project's web.config for authentication/DB connection string, and I should be able to access it via a dialog produced from our main project. For version 1, I don't require any sort of authentication and it would be a stand-alone project. I hope I'm making sense. I will add a few details to my question.